# How to remove the bottom panel of Gnome Classic in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, gnome-panel

I switched to Unity environment and there is a bottom panel of Gnome Classic that is not natural of the proper Unity. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running gnome-panel.  Check with:

```
ps -ef | grep panel
```

and you can see its process ID in second column.  For instance, a running panel for me shows like:

```
john      2324  2191  0 07:09 ?        00:01:11 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
john     15587 15557  0 14:18 pts/25   00:00:00 gnome-panel
john     15607 15557  0 14:20 pts/25   00:00:00 grep panel
```

You'll want to keep unit-panel-service.  Kill gnome-panel using its PID.  For me it goes away with:

```
kill -9 15587
```

Where the -9 forces the kill, but is maybe not necessary for this case.